# Inkscape: How to overlay objects with transparent fill?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm trying to create a spherical triangle with 3 circles placed on top of it in Inkscape. The fill of the circles and the triangle should be transparent. Here's my progress so far:

[image]

How do I cut the path of the triangle that goes inside the circle? I've tried the options in the **Path** menu such as Union, Difference, Intersection, etc. but none of them seem to do what I want.

Comment: Doesn't [Cut Path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) do wnat you need? Please include a sketch of your expected result.

Comment: Cut Path isn't working. No matter the order in which I select the triangle and the circle, it just deletes the circle.

Comment: You often have to duplicate the one or other object, when you do path operations, because the one on top is consumed by the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the circle by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+D. That generates another circle on the top.

Select the triangle holding shift at the same time. Now you should have the top circle and the triangle selected, one circle should be unselected. (BTW. learn how to make the selections in the layers panel, you see what is selected, what's not and what is the actual ordering of the shapes)

Goto Path > Cut Path. Top circle vanishes, one stays. (In succesful path operations the topmost path often vanishes. Here you started with making a copy.)

Select the tip of the triangle and press DEL